# image as button C4

Tags: ios, objective-c, c4

I'm trying to add an action once an image was tapped. I first tried adding a C4Button and then giving it an image but that didn't work out at all. So now I'm trying to just add a tap function to an image
here is the code

```
-(void)setup{
//IMAGE AS BUTTON
    C4Image *photoButtonImage=[C4Image imageNamed:@"icons-02.png"];
    photoButtonImage.height=NavBarHeight;
    photoButtonImage.center=CGPointMake(self.canvas.width/2, self.canvas.height-NavBarHeight/2);
    [self.canvas addImage:photoButtonImage];
    [photoButtonImage addGesture:TAP name:@"tap" action:@"tapped"];
}
-(void)tapped {
    C4Log(@"tapped!");
}
```

applying the `[photoButtonImage addGesture:TAP name:@"tap" action:@"tapped"];` method to `self` totally works fine but nothing happens if I add it to the image (`PhotoButtonImage`). 
I've looked into 2 answers ([Gesture controls crash when calling methods on C4WorkSpace.m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328896/gesture-controls-crash-when-calling-methods-on-c4workspace-m/16363693#16363693) and [How do I apply a UILongPressGestureRecognizer to a shape in C4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523255/how-do-i-apply-a-uilongpressgesturerecognizer-to-a-shape-in-c4/10524101#10524101)). They are for shapes and I thought it should just work the same for images, but apparently it doesn't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adam's answer is correct for gestures. Generally, you want to use them when you want some extra / custom functionality for objects.

However, in your case you want to simply use the image as a button, you can do the following to achieve that without having to use a gesture:

```
[self listenFor:@"touchesBegan" fromObject:photoImage andRunMethod:@"aMethod"];
```

The reason for this is that **all** C4 objects will post basic touch notifications by default.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that when you add the gesture to the `C4Image` you are calling the tapped method of `C4Image` not the tapped method you have provided in `C4Workspace.m`. What you need to do is to have the `C4Image` send a notification when it has been tapped, then have `C4Workspace.m` listen for the notification and trigger your `tapped` method.

```
[photoButtonImage addGesture:TAP name:@"tap" action:@"tapped:"];
[self listenFor:@"tapped" fromObject:photoButtonImage andRunMethod:@"tapped"];
```

When you add the gesture it is always best to add the colon in order call the method with arguments. This will guarantee that the notifications work as you intend.